# sklearn StratfiedShuffleSplit

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Can someone help me understand what StratifiedShuffleSplit does? I am new to this library. I understand the principle behind stratfied sampling however in terms of code what exactly does the StratifiedShuffleSplit function return?

The book I am reading has the following code, however I am not quite following.. Does the function actually add an index on the dataframe that distinguishes between test vs training, which is why they are then using .loc? And what exactly is it splitting the income_cat column by? Thanks!

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit

split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

for train_index, test_index in split.split(housing, housing["income_cat"]):
    strat_train_set = housing.loc[train_index]
    strat_test_set = housing.loc[test_index]
```

Comment: Refer this [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the function actually add an index on the dataframe that
>   distinguishes between test vs training, which is why they are then
>   using .loc?

It's not adding an index, the index is already there, but yes the function basically returns splits of the index so that then you can call it with `.loc`

> And what exactly is it splitting the income_cat column by?

The idea of Stratified Shuffle Split is that for each split it will keep the original distribution of the labels in y.